# value of local variable is gone?

Tags: c++

I have this implementation:

```
//header file:

InfoTables* localInforTable;

typedef txdr_int32 InfoTable;

typedef struct
{
  int sendID;
  InfoTable *data;
} InfoTables;

// in cpp file
void Retrieval::InfoTableCallBack(int sendID,
                  InfoTables& infoTables)
{
    localInforTable = new InfoTables();

    localInforTable.sendId=sendID;
    localInforTable->data = infoTables.data;

    printf("Data %d, %d\n", localInforTable.sendId, localInforTable->data[0]); // correct data
}

void Retrieval::CheckInfoData()
{
    printf("Data %d, %d\n", localInforTable.sendId, localInforTable->data[0]); // sendID is OK but data9[0] is just printing the address
}
```

I want to copy inforTables in the method InforTableCallBack to a local variable that I can use for other methods. However the data is clean up in CheckInfoData()?

Comment: Please post *real* code.  Construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).

Comment: All errors aside, aren't you basically already doing what you want with the `memcpy` to `data`? And you should, in general, use copy constructors with C++, not `memcpy`.

Comment: I have updated the real code

Answer (score 2):

There are various errors with the code. First, `data` does not point to any allocated memory. Second, [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy) will simply not work for a user defined types that are not trivially copyable. You could use `MyData`'s assignment operator instead:

```
void myMethod1(Mydata &otherdata)
{
  *data = otherdata;
}
```

Comment: @Aniket OK, it will work on some user defined types, i.e. ones that are trivially copyable.

Comment: makes me wonder if the OP is actually asking something for real, or just trolling

Answer (score 0):

Adding to juanchopanza's answer:

assuming that the code has a typo (and if it really is `memcpy()`)

`memcpy(&data, &otherdata, sizeof(otherdata));` will simply not work correctly because `data` is a pointer already. and '&' on a pointer is address of the pointer = simply wrong usage of `memcpy`